# GMT Timezone in formula fields?

Tags: formula, timezone

I have a field which calculates opendate-closeddate. It is in IST time zone and i need to display in GMT time whenever it is giving a result.

**Is it Possible to convert date/time from any timezone to GMT using a formula field ?**

Comment: Are you working on a default page or with a VF page with a custom controller (or extension)?

Comment: No. actually i need a formula which i should write in a formula field. Am not using any pages.

Comment: Actually i need to know about Is it Possible to convert date/time from any timezone to GMT using a formula field. If Possible, please help me how to do that.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think there's no way to do this at the moment. See this question for some more info; http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9633/time-zone-and-daylight-savings-calculations-to-a-text-field

Comment: It is not possible to convert date/time from any timezone to GMT using formula field.

Comment: Ankush can u please tell me what are the reasons that it is not possible to convert using formula field. @AnkushDureja

Answer (score 2):

Use this formula function to get DateTime using GMT time zone

> DATETIMEVALUE   : Returns a year, month, day and GMT time value

This is described in the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&language=en_US#DATETIMEVALUE)

**Note:** Using with function with static date like DATETIMEVALUE("2014-10-07 13:46:00") doesn't seems to be considering Daylight Saving Time (DST).
Above formula will return 10/7/2014 7:16 PM result i.e simply adding 5.30 hours to time.
Above function works fine with DATETIMEVALUE(now())

It is better if you can store actual date to convert in some field and use formula like this:

```
TEXT( Datetime field )
```

or

```
TEXT( DATETIMEVALUE( Datetime field) )
```

---

And the reason behind why you should avoid directly using

```
DATETIMEVALUE( Datetime field)
```

in the formula field is because the return type of this formula field would be Date/Time and when salesforce show them on UI, it will convert the representation according to the current logged in user locale.

Comment: Hi, This function is giving result correctly when the time is salesforce time, but it is giving wrong output when the time is our system time,i.e current time. if possible can u please explain this situation

Comment: Can you post the code snippet also.

Comment: DATETIMEVALUE("2014-10-07 05:32:00")

Comment: The above one is current time and another code which is working correctly is DATETIMEVALUE(now())

Comment: @Madhuri Please check my updated answer. That will surely help.

Comment: Hi aditi!! I have tried ur formula, but it is giving same date which i have given in formula, it is not converting to GMT!! :(

Comment: I hope inside the formula you are using some salesforce field not hard-coded date. I have tested this formula before posting and it is giving correct result to me.